# unhashable type dict pymongo

Tags: python, pymongo

im using pycharm and im building a discord bot,i have a command that adds swear words to a certain list,
in order to save those words forever i've decided to use pymongo,im new to it,when i tried to run a quick test to see if it was working i got an error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/hp/PycharmProjects/untitled/new_bot.py", line 14, in 
    collection.insert_one({data})
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

i tried looking up this error in stackoverflow,i've found 1 or 2 answers to problems like it but i didnt understand them since i'm as stated above new to pymongo

here's the code(without the bot code and imports):

```
cluster = pymongo.MongoClient("stuff that should be copied from site")
db = cluster["database name"]
collection = db["collection name"]
data = {"_id": some int id her", "name": "hubabuba"}
collection.insert_one({data})
```

Comment: You can't put a dictionary in a set; this doesn't have anything to do with `pymongo`. What's your intent with `{data}`? Do you mean just `collection.insert_one(data)`?

Comment: oh god,thanks,i've tried this and it worked, i just watched a tutorial and the guy put post(in my case data) in curly brackets,i guess it was an outdated tutorial,or i'm just blind,still thanks though

Comment: In the tutorial, they may have given the dictionary directly to `insert_one` instead of using a intermediate variable like your `data`, and you misread it as a set. Sets (`{a, b}`) look very similar to dictionaries (`{a: z}`).